# semantic form validation - Validation for either one of the fields as non-empty

Tags: semantic-ui

I have a form in which I have 2 fields, ssn and phone. I would like the user to enter anyone of the field. I'm using semantic validation, here is my code, can you please let me know how to validate the form using Semantic?

```
<form class="ui error form basic segment" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/username/email') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
    <div class="ui info message">
        Please enter either SSN or phone to email you the username.
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="ssn">SSN</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ssn" value="{{ old('ssn') }}">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="ui icon input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}">  
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Email Username" class="ui primary button"> 

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.ui.form')
      .form({
        inline : true,
        on: 'blur',
        fields: {
          username: {
            identifier : 'ssn',
            rules: [
              {
                type   : 'empty',
                prompt : 'Please enter a SSN'
              }
            ]
          },
        }
      })
    ;
</script>
```

`

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your code? I tried running it and it works fine for me. By default, the value of the "ssn" is populated, so submitting without typing anything will validate properly because there is already text. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k749gm55/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a Semantic UI custom validation function that accepts parameters for your purpose.
Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/owcfuhtq/

The code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // function to check if at least one text is not empty for a collection of elements
    // text is the value of the input device
    // csv is the argument as string. It's the string inside "[" and "]"
    $.fn.form.settings.rules.isAllEmpty = function(text,csv){
        //If the text of the field itself isn't empty, then it is valid
        if (text)
            return true;
        var array = csv.split(','); // you're separating the string by commas
        var isValid = false; // return value

        $.each(array,function(index,elem){
            // for each item in array, get an input element with the specified name, and check if it has any values
            var element = $("input[name='"+elem+"']");
            //If element is found, and it's value is not empty, then it is valid
            if (element && element.val())
                isValid = true;
        });
        return isValid; 
    };

    var formValidationRules =
    {
        ssn: {
          identifier: 'ssn',
          rules: [{
            type: "isAllEmpty[phone]",
            //If you got additional fields to compare, append it inside the [] with a "," separator
            //E.g. isAllEmpty[field1, field2]
            prompt: 'An error occurred'
          }]
        }
    }

    $('.ui.form').form(formValidationRules);

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little bit more elegant solution that follows [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) fields identification standard.
Field could be identified not only via `input[name="…"]` CSS selector offered in [Oniisaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4229687/oniisaki)'s accepted answer, but also by DOM element id or `data-validation` attribute:

```js
/**
 * Checks whether current field value or at least one of additionally 
 *   given fields values is not empty, neither blank string.
 * @param {string} value Current field value.
 * @param {string} fieldIdentifiers Comma separated field identifiers.
 * @return {boolean}
 */
$.fn.form.settings.rules.allEmpty = function(value, fieldIdentifiers) {
  var $form = $(this);

  return !!value || fieldIdentifiers.split(',').some(function(fieldIdentifier) {
    return $form.find('#' + fieldIdentifier).val() ||
        $form.find('[name="' + fieldIdentifier +'"]').val() ||
        $form.find('[data-validate="'+ fieldIdentifier +'"]').val();

  });
};


// Using newly created custom validation rule.
// Notice how multiple fields are defined, if required.
$('.ui.form').form({
  ssn: {
    identifier: 'ssn',
    rules: [{

      // Multiple field identifiers could be defined, 
      // like `allEmpty[phone,email,skype]`.
      type: 'allEmpty[phone]',
      prompt: 'SSN or Phone (at least one field) must be filled.'
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include select box you can use it sth like this :

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.isAllEmpty = function (text, csv) {
    if (text) {
        return true;
    }
    var array = csv.split(',');
    var isValid = false;

    $.each(array, function (index, elem) {
        var element = $("input[name='" + elem + "']");

        if (element.length == 0) {
            element = $("select[name='" + elem + "']")
        }

        if (element && element.val()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
};
```